Panic on Command::new trying to launch teamspeak 3
I'm learning Rust and am currently using the Command::new(1) method to run processes external to my application.
Until today, everything was working pretty well. But there is one program that causes panic: Teamspeak 3.
It's the only program I've encountered that causes this.
I show you the code:
Command::new(r#"C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak 3 Client\ts3client_win64"#)
 .arg("")
 .spawn()
 .expect("Failed to execute process Teamspeak 3.");

This is very simple code and yet it doesn't work.
(I tested with other executables and it's run perfectly).
I am open to any suggestions to help me find or at least guide me in my research to resolve this problem.
Thanks.

Are you missing the final .exe in the path to the binary?

In the Implementations part you have a "Platform-specific behavior" section which indicates that under Windows the .exe is not mandatory.

What does the error say? "not found"? or something else? (also does teamspeak really want an empty argument?)

The only message I can see in the step-by-step execution is that of expect().
If I put the command in a std::panic::catch_unwind(|| { ...}); the program panics as well on the teamspeak line and quit.

expect() will also output the error value itself. In fact, you can't use expect() with error values that can't be formatted, so there is definitely more to the error message that you either aren't seeing or aren't sharing with us.

cdhowie, thank you, but contrary to what you think, I don't intentionally hide information. I put the command line into a simple rust program and got the full stacktrace. So somewhere in my code the return from expect() is obfuscated.
Result, the requested execution requires an elevation.
